# Adding separate arrows on d3 network graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to add separate arrows (one for the path from node A to B, and the other for B to A) to a d3 graph that I have made (see the Plunker version [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vo5Qt7WP0V6Zdp4h7Z0L)), instead of adding a single arrow with two arrows at each end.

I have tried the code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278), by changing my 'tick' function, as well as defining a path variable to be as below:

```
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
.data(force.links())
 .enter().append("svg:path")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

function tick() {
path.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + 
        d.source.x + "," + 
        d.source.y + "A" + 
        dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
        d.target.x + "," + 
        d.target.y;
});
```

However, this seems to stop the nodes from displaying, as well as the zoom/filtering functionality.

Does anyone know how I can stop this happening?

Best,

Ben

Comment: fiddle seems to be working as u r expecting

Comment: there's a console error... i'm sure.

Comment: Ok, any idea how I can rectify this?